# AES-NI not passed to guest in Virtualbox

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, encryption, i386

I'm trying to use encryption inside a virtual machine. The problem is that the AES-NI doesn't seem to be passed to the guest virtual machine.

I have Vt-x enabled.

This is my host cpuinfo:

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 42
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz
stepping        : 7
cpu MHz         : 1600.000
cache size      : 8192 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 8
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt aes xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips        : 6801.03
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

This is my guest cpuinfo:

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 42
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz
stepping        : 7
cpu MHz         : 3399.615
cache size      : 6144 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 2
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 2
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 5
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl pni ssse3 lahf_lm
bogomips        : 6799.23
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Am I missing some configuration option? Or is this a problem of Virtualbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the normal state in Virtualbox, see [here](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=42951).

Comment: I know it's you who asked there (& got the answer), but you haven't provided the feedback here :)

Comment: Linking to an answer on another forum that provides ZERO additional information that the statement you made isn't particularly helpful. Perhaps you could find and link the actual bug where this is discussed.

Comment: @Caleb: I thought it's helpful because it's more official. should I remove the link? (couldn't find a discussion on their Bugtracker).